# Default input dimensions for an image in Neural networks?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Reading a PyTorch book, I came across this code where the authors change the order of the axis.

img_t.permute(1, 2, 0) (Changes the order of the axes from C × H × W to H × W × C)

Is H x W x C the default input dimensions for an input image in Neural networks?

Comment: Can you share code where he did it? what's img_t? Pytorch expects [N,C,H,W]

Comment: See [EpyNN](https://epynn.net/Convolution.html#shapes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PyTorch inputs are bathes in shape N x C x H x W. So N is a batch size, C  is a number of image channels, H and W are height and width as you know. But when you work with for instance cv2, default shape of images is HxWxC so you need to swap dimensions for pytorch.

Comment: Now I get it. It was tensor and they wanted to show the image. So they converted it so they use it in imshow().